# determine the centre points of the circle

Tags: geometry, circles

**Given:**

- Circle with centre $M (-5; 5)$
- The equation is $(x+5)^2 + (y-5)^2 = 50$

Suppose this figure is translated $6$ units to the right and $3$ units down. What is the new centre of the circle?

**My attempt** for the centre is $x + 6$ and $y - 3$, yielding $M (1; 2)$,
but the answer in the textbook is $M (1; 5)$

Explain?

Comment: Explain?  Typo.  6 units to the right of -5 is 1.  3 units down from 5 is 2 so the center is (1,2).  That's it.  Unambiguous and inarguable.  The book is wrong.  I don't the book author is stupid so ... I must conclude it is an uncaught typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation implies the circle center at $(-5,5)$ indeed, which is your point $M$. Moving 6 right and 3 down should yield
$$
(-5,5) + (6,-3) = (-5+6,5-3) = (1,2)
$$

Could be a typo in the book?